# How to remove base path in Zend view path when using addScriptPath / setScriptPath?

Tags: zend-framework

Using an old copy of Zend 1.6. Trying to combine some views, and was trying to use addScriptPath, the only issue is that the path it looks for is

```
/scripts/common/controller_related_dir/view
```

I still need to keep

```
/scripts/controller_related_dir/view
```

but in cases I use addScriptPath or setScriptPath I need it to be

```
/scripts/common/view
```

I'm pretty new to Zend and am struggling to figure out where to even start to fix this.